# List all resources of installed app (through reflection) doesn't work as excepted

Tags: java, android, reflection, android-resources

I need to get a list of all resources of an application. As android doesn't provide a specific I started using reflection to get the R class of the app and read its fields. The code is the following:

//

This works with the same app and with another app developed by me(but not signed/zipaligned. Installed with a debug key), but not with the others. Then it throws this exception(in this example i tried it with the facebook app):

```
W/System.err﹕ java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.katana.R" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.facebook.katana-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
W/System.err﹕ at com.example.restest.MyActivity$Adapter.listDrawables(MyActivity.java:59)
W/System.err﹕ at com.example.restest.MyActivity$Adapter.<init>(MyActivity.java:46)
W/System.err﹕ at com.example.restest.MyActivity.set(MyActivity.java:37)
More, unimportant stuff
```

Did I forget something, or do I need some permissions? My app needs root so this wouldn't be a problem!

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If the other classes are not on the classpath, you obviously can't load them. You *could* pull the `.apk` from `/data/app` and unzip, then javap/disassemble/have_fun_with to check for the individual fields.

Comment: I'm looking to achieve the same thing. I don't know what's preventing reflection from getting those classes - permissions or non-existence at that place. Help me if you've figure this out.